# String split & join

Tags: java

I have a collection of strings. I need to be able to join the items in this collection into one string and afterwards split that string backwards and get original string collection. 
Definitely I need to introduce a delimiter character for join/split operation. Given the fact that original strings can contain any characters, I also need to deal with delimiter escaping. My question is very simple - is there a Java class/library that can provide me required functionality out-of-the-box? Something like:

```
String join(String[] source, String delimiter, String escape);
String[] split(String source, String delimiter, String escape);
```

or similar, without having to do the work manually?

Comment: show something you tried. BTW, join-and-then-split will always have possibility that your `<seperator>` is one of the (or part of) input Strings.

Comment: AFAIK, none of the solutions suggested so far support escaping.

Comment: OK, I'm curious. *Why* are you joining a string, then splitting it? It sounds like you need something else!

Answer (score 6):

Without the escaping part, there are:

- `StringUtils.split(..)` and `StringUtils.join(..)` from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)
- `Joiner` and `Splitter` from [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

Splitting: `String.split` takes regex pattern as argument (delimeter) and returns `String[]` as result.

Answer (score 0):

Split and Join escaping separator:

```
@NonNull
public static String joinEscaping(char separator, String... aa) {
    String escape = separator != '\\' ? "\\" : "#"; 

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
        String a = aa[i];
        a = (a == null) ? "" : a;
        a = a.replace(escape, escape + escape);
        a = a.replace(separator + "", escape + separator);

        result.append(a);
        if (i + 1 < aa.length) {
            result.append(separator);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}


public static List<String> splitUnescaping(char separator, @NonNull String str) {
    char escape = separator != '\\' ? '\\' : '#';
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int yourAreHere = 0;
    boolean newPart = true;

    while (true) {
        int sep = str.indexOf(separator, yourAreHere);
        int exc = str.indexOf(escape, yourAreHere);
        if (sep == -1 && exc == -1) { // last part
            add(result, str.substring(yourAreHere), newPart);
            break;
        }
        if (sep == -1 && exc + 1 == str.length()) { // ghost escape
            add(result, str.substring(yourAreHere, exc), newPart);
            break;
        }
        if (exc == -1 || (sep != -1 && sep < exc)) {
            add(result, str.substring(yourAreHere, sep), newPart);
            yourAreHere = sep + 1;
            newPart = true;
        } else {
            char next = str.charAt(exc + 1);
            add(result, str.substring(yourAreHere, exc) + next, newPart);
            yourAreHere = exc + 2;
            newPart = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}


private static void add(List<String> result, String part, boolean newPart) {
    if (newPart) {
        result.add(part);
    } else {
        int last = result.size() - 1;
        result.set(last, result.get(last) + part);
    }
}
```