# Escaped string split & join

Tags: javascript, string, split, escaping

Similar to [String split & join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130146/string-split-join), but for Javascript:

I have an Array of strings. I need to be able to join the items into one string and afterwards split that string again to get the original string collection. However, each string may contain the joining string as well, so I’ll have to do some escaping. Are there any recipes on how to achieve that?

Here is an example:

```
serialized = ["Hello", ",", "World"].join(",") # Nice would be "Hello,\,,World"
```

But

```
serialized.split(",")
```

returns `["Hello", "", "", "World"]` instead of `["Hello", ",", "World"]`

Comment: OK, I'm curious.  *Why* are you joining a string, then splitting it?  It sounds like you need something else!

Comment: The behaviour above is correct since you're joining with comma and comma is also the one of the joined strings...

Comment: Indeed, the purpose is "pretty" serialization. I’d like to keep everything that join and split do except to also allow strings to contain the joining char as illustrated.

Comment: Oh, `.join()` doesn't actually serialize an array as you have discovered, that's `.toString()`. De-serialization is the unfortunate `eval()` statement. That's not to say you can't override the `.join()` and `.split()` functions.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: I don't mind using a custom function for that, but was just looking for anything besides manually switch-casing over each character in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it manually I came up with this, in case anyone ever stumbles on this again ;)

```
splitAndUnescape = function(character, str, opt_escapeChar) {
  var result = [];
  var escapeChar = opt_escapeChar || '\\';
  var tmp = '';
  for (var index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
    var ch = str.charAt(index);
    if (ch == escapeChar) {
      ch = str.charAt(++index);
    } else if (ch == character) {
      result.push(tmp);
      tmp = '';
      continue;
    }
    tmp += ch;
  }
  if (tmp || result.length) {
    result.push(tmp);
  }
  return result;
};

escapeAndJoin = function(character, array, opt_escapeChar) {
  var escapeChar = opt_escapeChar || '\\';
  var reEscape = new RegExp('(\\' + character + '|\\' + escapeChar + ')', 'g');
  var out = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    out.push(array[index].replace(reEscape, escapeChar + '$1'));
  }
  return out.join(character);
};
```

PoC:

```
serialized = escapeAndJoin(",", ["Hello", ",", "World"]); # -> "Hello,\,,World"
splitAndUnescape(",", serialized) # -> ["Hello", ",", "World"]
```

Comment: I just thought the API would be more friendly as `Array.prototype.escapedJoin` and `String.prototype.escapedSplit`.

Comment: @J.H. I don’t think that’s correct as the escape character is also escaped, e.g.

    `splitAndUnescape(",", escapeAndJoin(",", ["A", "\\B"]))
    -> ["A", "\\B"]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` instead.

```
JSON.stringify(["Hello", ",", "World"]) // -> '["Hello",",","World"]'
JSON.parse('["Hello",",","World"]') // -> ["Hello", ",", "World"]
```

Comment: beware, JSON depend on browser ... You'll need a specific script link for old IE

Comment: While this obviously works great, one additional requirement is that the string should look "nice", i.e. not contain too much boilerplate (it'll be put in an URL and I want to avoid %.. escaped stuff).

Comment: @solisoft that right thank you for mentioning it. Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3.1+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, and Opera 10.5+ support native JSON parsing.